# Entity Framework: Unable to load one or more of the requested types

Tags: entity-framework

I am getting a specific exception that I am confused about.  I recently changed the target framework of my application from .net Framework 4.0 client profile to .net Framework 4.5.  That has apparently caused my entity framework to go a little haywire. I get this exception when I run my application...

```
System.Reflection.ReflectionTypeLoadException: Unable to load one or more of the requested types. Retrieve the
LoaderExceptions property for more information.
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeModule.GetTypes(RuntimeModule module)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeModule.GetTypes()
   at System.Reflection.Assembly.GetTypes()
   at System.Data.EntityUtil.GetTypesSpecial(Assembly assembly)
   at System.Data.Metadata.Edm.ObjectItemAttributeAssemblyLoader.LoadTypesFromAssembly()
   at System.Data.Metadata.Edm.ObjectItemAssemblyLoader.Load()
   at System.Data.Metadata.Edm.ObjectItemAttributeAssemblyLoader.Load()
   at System.Data.Metadata.Edm.AssemblyCache.LoadAssembly(Assembly assembly, Boolean loadReferencedAssemblies, ObjectItemLoadingSessionData loadingData)
```

The thing is it used to work before I made this change... What did I manage to mess up?  Do I need to regenerate these entities?  How do I go about trouble shooting and fixing this problem?  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two ways to debug this:

1. Run your program in the debugger, turn on break-on-unhandled exceptions and then inspect the LoaderExceptions property of the exception like the message says.  That should give you an idea of which type is not loading.
2. Run [fuslogvw.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e74a18c4.aspx) and inspect the failure that is logged there.  If an assembly was not found or could not be loaded, it will tell you which one and possibly why.